# Azure AD Connect filtering groups

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I’m starting to use Azure AD Connect ,but using the express install it’s been imported everything from my On-premises AD, but I would like to filter groups or just set what groups I would like to import to AAD.
How could I do that?

Answer (score 0):

When you start AAD Connect, instead of choosing Express settings choose **Customize**.  Then, in the **Sync > Filtering** section select the group(s) you want to synchronize.

[image]

Comment: Hi @RickRainey thank you for the help, but i'm choosing Customize and this Filtering option does not appear to me.

below Sync it's appearing only,
- Connect Directories
- Optional Features
- Directory Extensions
- Azure AD Apps
- Azure AD Attributes

Comment: Are you certain you have the latest version?  http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=47594

Answer (score 0):

I might suggest creating a group explicitly for use in the filter users screenshot. What I found to be missing in the documentation however is the screen before the illustration you provided. Like most domains, you have users in various OUs. Make sure you add any OU that contains users you want to sync. Then choose the "Synchronize Selected" and enter your sync group. Then add the desired users to that group, maybe one at a time to verify desired results. The documentation on AD Connect, while abundant, is simultaneously full of omissions.

And you'll run into some gotchas as well. Today, I stumbled onto fragments of an random post that suggested that if a user had added a mailbox (such as a shared mailbox that several users are connected to) their primary mailbox will not sync. I have been seeing this behavior and yet I have yet to find conclusive documentation to confirm or deny this roadblock.

Good luck!